# How to sort multidimensional array with PHP?

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I've an array like below, what I want is to display record having row at the bottom whose "quotes" array is empty.

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [id] => 0
        [regNo] => LHR7171
        [quotes] => Array
            (
            )

    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [id] => 2
        [regNo] => YN09 BYY (9)
        [quotes] => Array
            (
somevalues in array format
            )

    )
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reference: all basic ways to sort arrays and data in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17364127/reference-all-basic-ways-to-sort-arrays-and-data-in-php)

Answer (score 1):

```
uasort(
    $i,
   function($value1, $value2) {
       return count($value2['quotes']) - count($value1['quotes']);
    }
);
```

And regarding the tags below your question: this has (of course) absolutely nothing to do with SF2 or Twig. This is just plain PHP.

Comment: I tried this but it didn't sorted array, where I'm making mistake.

        uasort(
                $finalResult, function($finalResult, $finalResult) {
                    return count($finalResult['quotes']) - count($finalResult['quotes']);
                }
        );

Comment: How do you expect that to work when you use the same variable name for both function arguments?

Comment: ok my mistake, i changed variable, its still not sorting like i need

        uasort(
                $finalResult, function($value1, $value2) {
                    return count($value2['quotes']) - count($value1['quotes']);
                }
        );

Comment: @Umair So what does it do? What result do you get? If you have code which isn't working, edit your question, add that code, clarify what it does and what it should do instead.